# Persisting changes in dataset to sqlite database

Tags: c#, sqlite, ado.net

I'm new to ADO.NET. I am struggling with persisting changes in my dataset to my sqlite database.

It has a table "Category" which has 3 fields:  CategoryID(int), CategoryName(varchar(100), Parent(int). parent can be null.

I am trying to insert a new row into my database. I have the following code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SQLite;
using System.Text;

namespace QS_Optimized
{
    class UsingDataset
    {
        static DataSet dataset;
        static SQLiteConnection conn;

        static UsingDataset()
        {
            conn = new SQLiteConnection("data source = ..\\sqlitedb_amrit.db");
            dataset = new DataSet("MyDataset");
        }

        public static void UpdateFromDB()
        {
            SQLiteDataAdapter sqda = new SQLiteDataAdapter("Select Category.* from Category where Parent = 0", conn);
            sqda.Fill(dataset, "Category");
            //dataset.Tables["Category"].Columns["CategoryID"].AllowDBNull = false;
            //dataset.Tables["Category"].Columns["CategoryName"].AllowDBNull = false;

            // Insert command
            SQLiteCommand cmdInsert = new SQLiteCommand();
            cmdInsert.Connection = conn;
            cmdInsert.CommandText = @"Insert into Category('CategoryID','CategoryName','Parent') values" +
                @"(@id,@name,@parent)";
            cmdInsert.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@id",DbType.Int64));
            cmdInsert.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@name",DbType.String));
            cmdInsert.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@parent",DbType.Int64));
            sqda.InsertCommand = cmdInsert;

            // Add Datarows to dataset;
            DataTable tbl = dataset.Tables["Category"];
            DataRow drw = tbl.NewRow();
            drw[0] = 64;
            drw[1] = "TestCategory";
            drw[2] = 0;
            tbl.Rows.Add(drw);

            sqda.Update(dataset,"Category");
        }

        public static void Main()
        {
            UpdateFromDB();           
        }           
    }
}
```

When I execute it, I get an exception:

> Category.Categoryname may not be NULL

.
Why is this error coming? I don't think I'm inserting a null

Also, when I allow nulls in that particular column (change done in database), this code inserts a new row

> (64,NULL,NULL)

into the table in database. I already have 63 records in the table right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep it simple.  Just use a SQLite Command object.  Set the sql to be

> Insert into tablename(col1, col2,
>   col3)  VALUES(@val1, @val2, @val3)

Then pass the values into the parameters collection of the command object.  This way you'll have an easier time of debugging, being that you can look at each parameter value at runtime.